# Move multiple file from local unix to HDFS

Tags: unix, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I have several files in a unix directory that I have to move to Hadoop. I know the copyFromLocal command:

> Usage: hadoop fs -copyFromLocal  URI but that allows me to
>   move one by one.

Is there any way to move all those files to the HDFS in one command?

I want to know if there is a way to transfer several files at once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put command will work

if you want to copy whole directory from local to hdfs

```
hadoop fs -put /path1/file1 /pathx/target/
```

if you want to copy all files from directory  to hdfs in one go

```
hadoop fs -put /path1/file1/* /pathx/target/
```

Answer (score 1):

The put command supports multiple sources

> Copy single src, or multiple srcs from local file system to the destination file system